# Running Selenium tests on a server using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, ubuntu, firefox

I am trying to set up an Ubuntu server so it can run Selenium tests, using javascript.

I started a new droplet on Digital ocean, and ran the following commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
apt-get install default-jre
apt-get install npm
curl -O http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar
```

Then, in a new terminal:

```
npm init
npm install webdriverio
touch main.js
```

In main.js, I add the following code, from [this page](http://webdriver.io/guide.html):

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
    .end();
```

Then I run the command:

```
node main
```

Which fails silently. Looking back at the first terminal, I see a giant error message.

```
19:46:13.910 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@6aa523f8, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.2.16, url=http://webdriver.io}}]])
19:46:13.912 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{rotatable=true, locationContextEnabled=true, loggingPrefs=org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingPreferences@6aa523f8, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, requestOrigins={name=webdriverio, version=4.2.16, url=http://webdriver.io}}]
19:46:13.914 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-sel', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:166)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-sel', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.newInstance(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.FirefoxDriverProvider.callConstructor(FirefoxDriverProvider.java:91)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-sel', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.Executable.<init>(Executable.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.<init>(FirefoxBinary.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getBinary(FirefoxDriver.java:203)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
    ... 14 more
19:46:13.916 WARN - Exception: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ubuntu-sel', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

It looks like the error might be that I don't have Firefox installed, but I am not sure what that means in this environment. Since it's just command line on a server, I can't just go to the firefox website and download and install it.

What do I need to do differently? I don't really care if I use firefox or chrome, or possibly some other simpler browser. Just want to get this basic script running!

**Update:**

I ran these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
apt-get update
```

then stopped and started the java selenium command. Now when I run `node main` I don't see any errors in the selenium terminal, but I also don't see the title getting logged.

Comment: You can install Firefox/Chrome through the command line by adding the specific repo and then running `apt-get install <package-name>`. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion).

Comment: @usandfriends I ran `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa` and `apt-get update`, but was getting the same error. So I restarted the selenium process, and now I don't get any errors, but I still don't get the title log that I'm aiming for.

Comment: Can you verify the mozilla process runs when selenium runs?